# Why am I receiving the same transaction hash twice?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

Can you please explain to me why the following code is receiving the same transaction hash twice? I want to avoid that

```js
var Web3 = require('web3')
    const web3Subs = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/XXX'))
    const web3Trx = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/XXX'))
    const subscription = web3Subs.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions')
    subscription.subscribe((error, txHash) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log(txHash + " received.");
    })
```

output :

```
0x98219dad048aef55649d334a42c69ad094d3be1378f68b294aeaa2ef49ae2f97 received.
test.js:10
0x98219dad048aef55649d334a42c69ad094d3be1378f68b294aeaa2ef49ae2f97 received.
test.js:10
0x7f19d86f3c08c171060b0c29c0ad889dd7b2e69188ff6c8314caa4fb65e5b6a0 received.
test.js:10
0x7f19d86f3c08c171060b0c29c0ad889dd7b2e69188ff6c8314caa4fb65e5b6a0 received.
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like a web3 issue, rather an RxJS issue or whatever library you're using to make those subscribe calls... You're subscribing twice, so I'd imagine that's why you're seeing things firing twice.

```
const subscription = web3Subs.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions'); // You subscribe here
subscription.subscribe((error, txHash) => {  // And you subscribe again to that subscription
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log(txHash + " received.");
    })
```

I'd imagine this might give you better results if you wrote it this way, as you don't subscribe twice and still assign the subscription to a variable in case you need to reference it:

```
const subscription = web3Subs.eth.subscribe((error, txHash) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log(txHash + " received.");
    });
```